# getOptionChain() with expiration date doesn't seem to limit to the specified date

Tags: r, finance, quantmod

I've tried the following to get the AAPL option chain with expiration date April 19 2014:

```
try1 <- getOptionChain("AAPL",Exp="2014-04-19")
try2 <- getOptionChain("AAPL",Exp=as.Date("2014-04-19"))
```

Results of both are identical and seem to be *all* options expiring in April:

```
> try1$puts
                     Strike   Last    Chg    Bid    Ask  Vol    OI
AAPL140419P00200000   200.0   0.05   0.00     NA   0.05    1    37
# <snip>
AAPL140411P00470000   470.0   0.30   0.05   0.25   0.42   10    43
# <snip>
```

The above snips of the chain shows options for April 19 2014 but also e.g. April 11 2014.

What am I doing wrong? I am running "R 3.0.2 GUI 1.62 Snow Leopard build (6558)" with new quantmod install from CRAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getOptionChain` scrapes the data from Yahoo's webpage.  Yahoo only provides data by expiration month, not by the specific day.

You can use the `expiry` function in [the greeks package](https://code.google.com/p/rgreeks/) to determine which contracts expire on a specific day:

```
> head(try1$puts[as.Date(expiry(rownames(try1$puts))) == "2014-04-19",])
                    Strike Last Chg Bid Ask Vol OI
AAPL140419P00200000    200 0.05   0  NA  NA   1 37
AAPL140419P00205000    205 0.15   0  NA  NA   0 25
AAPL140419P00210000    210 0.35   0  NA  NA   0 11
AAPL140419P00215000    215 0.01   0  NA  NA   2  9
AAPL140419P00220000    220 0.13   0  NA  NA   0 23
AAPL140419P00225000    225 0.80   0  NA  NA   0 12
```

Note that you will have to build and install the greeks package from source yourself.

Or you can grep for the date yourself:

```
> head(try1$puts[grepl("140419", rownames(try1$puts)),])
                    Strike Last Chg Bid Ask Vol OI
AAPL140419P00200000    200 0.05   0  NA  NA   1 37
AAPL140419P00205000    205 0.15   0  NA  NA   0 25
AAPL140419P00210000    210 0.35   0  NA  NA   0 11
AAPL140419P00215000    215 0.01   0  NA  NA   2  9
AAPL140419P00220000    220 0.13   0  NA  NA   0 23
AAPL140419P00225000    225 0.80   0  NA  NA   0 12
```

Comment: Thank you. Ultimately, I ended up parsing the optionID in the rowname but your parse is much nicer.

Comment: If this answers your question, please consider following the advice from [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).